# Select cell value from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have multiple records in table .. Scenario when I click on row then chart is display according to ID now I want to specify that which owner have this data so for this I try to display owner name ..

I have data in a table:

```
ID      Owner RegNo 
26626   John  B82       
26634   David BE49  
26642   Roh   A5    
26640   Julie B5
```

I tried this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#tabledata').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var Id = row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
            var cell = row.find('td')[1].firstChild.data;
            var obj = {};
            var cellvalue = {};
            obj.ID = Id;
            cellvalue.cell = cell;
            GetData(obj);
            return false;
        });
    });
function GetData(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetVo",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
                   if (result !== null && result.length == 0) {
                $("#cont").hide();
                return;
            }
            strArray = result.d;
            var myarray = eval(strArray);
            $("#cont").show();
            $('#cont').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    borderColor: 'Grey',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    type: 'pie',
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: true,
                        alpha: 45
                    }

                },

                title: {
                    text: JSON.stringify(cellvalue)
                },

                position: {
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        x: 10,
                        y: -10
                  },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Chart'
                    //text: 'Total: ' + myarray.length
                },


                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        innerSize: 100,
                        depth: 45,
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}',
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Delivered amount',
                    data: myarray
                }]
            });

            //end
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }

    });
        }

    //  });


  </script>
```

when I check f12 this shows the error

> WebForm1.aspx:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: cellvalue is not defined

Comment: Your cellvalue is not in scope for line: `text: JSON.stringify(cellvalue)`

Comment: You can pass cellvalue to `GetData(obj);` as `GetData(obj, cellvalue);`.

Comment: but if i call this function GetData(obj,cellvalue) then i have to call there also function GetData(obj).. i dont want to call in this .. i only want when we select on row then i want to get owner cell value in label

Comment: `$('#tabledata').on('click', 'tr', function () {})` This function calls `GetData(obj)`. You just have to modify that. And this `function GetData(obj)` you have to modify. Your `function GetData(obj)` is invoked when you click your row, as per your code.

Comment: Just in case you do not want to modify your code, then you will have to make your cellvalue as global. But I would say please avoid that for such an easy solution.

Comment: wow this is working.. but this show commas on start and end  like this .  "JOHN "

Comment: I will post it as answer then. Do mark it correct, if it solved your problem. Also about the "JOHN" thingy, even I have no idea. I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify You function calling and function definition:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#tabledata').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var Id = row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
            var cell = row.find('td')[1].firstChild.data;
            var obj = {};
            var cellvalue = {};
            obj.ID = Id;
            cellvalue.cell = cell;
            GetData(obj, cellvalue); //HERE
            return false;
        });
    });
function GetData(obj, cellvalue) { //AND HERE
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetVo",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
                   if (result !== null && result.length == 0) {
                $("#cont").hide();
                return;
            }
            strArray = result.d;
            var myarray = eval(strArray);
            $("#cont").show();
            $('#cont').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    borderColor: 'Grey',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    type: 'pie',
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: true,
                        alpha: 45
                    }

                },

                title: {
                    text: JSON.stringify(cellvalue)
                },

                position: {
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        x: 10,
                        y: -10
                  },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Chart'
                    //text: 'Total: ' + myarray.length
                },


                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        innerSize: 100,
                        depth: 45,
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}',
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Delivered amount',
                    data: myarray
                }]
            });

            //end
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }

    });
        }

    //  });


  </script>
```

Comment: and what about " "??

Comment: I'm checking. Will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: You are using stringify, maybe thats why you are getting " ". Can you use the variable directly, instead of json.stringify.